# Code not compiling in nodejs,throws out an unexpected error(Web3.js)

Tags: node.js, blockchain, solidity, web3js

I tried following this [repo](https://github.com/maheshmurthy/ethereum_voting_dapp/tree/master/chapter1):-

But I  am getting the following error on compiling the code with :-

```
code = fs.readFileSync('Voting.sol').toString()
solc = require('solc')
compiledCode = solc.compile(code)
```

It throws out this error:-

```
'{"errors":[{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"* Line 1, Column 1\\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\\n* Line 1, Column 2\\n  Extra non-whitespace after JSON value.\\n","message":"* Line 1, Column 1\\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\\n* Line 1, Column 2\\n  Extra non-whitespace after JSON value.\\n","severity":"error","type":"JSONError"}]}'
```

Comment: You better go on the repo to open an issue there. (I assume you already checked the opened issues)

Comment: Hey @Izio , i did open an issue but looks like the developer is inactive for few days. A fast help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the `code` variable? If it's some sol file then how did you read it?

Comment: Also since the compilation is done by Solidity why don't you google https://www.google.com/search?q=solidity+Syntax+error%3A+value%2C+object+or+array+expected.&oq=solidity+Syntax+error%3A+value%2C+object+or+array+expected.

Comment: Hey @Molda, i have updated the code, please look into it. I did google it, but was not able to find an appropriate answer. Thanks

Comment: The compile function takes different arguments depending on which version you have. Make sure to check documentation https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js#readme

Comment: Have you solved it somehow? I have the same problem.

Comment: I have been busy since few days will resume today. No, i didn't get any solution for it yet.

Comment: Hey, @BananaCake i found the answer. Please check below.

Comment: @abhinayak Thank you, but can you be more specific about the npm and solc conflict?

Comment: @BananaCake go through this link :-https://github.com/maheshmurthy/ethereum_voting_dapp/issues/16

Comment: @abhinayak I'm not following the tutorial so I don't have any package.json file. I have only HelloWorld.sol with the Solidity code and I get this error whenever I want to compile it.

Comment: hey, @BananaCake, it's because of the package version problems. try matching the package version as shown in the tutorial.

Comment: @abhinayak I found another solution that works for me and solidity 0.5.1. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer it was because of the npm version conflicts. Make sure that you have the right version of solc.Refer this [repo](https://github.com/Juneyoung-Kang/ethereum_voting_dapp.git)

Answer (score 12):

I found that if you put your input info into the JSON format per the solidity docs, then you are good regardless of the compiler. Before compiling "stringify" the file (JSON.stringify). After the file is compiled the object will be in string form, so then you may want to parse it (JSON.parse) to work with it from there. Here is a code sample with a console.log() of the contract in JSON form so you can see what you are working with.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');


const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');

var solcInput = {
    language: "Solidity",
    sources: { 
        contract: {
            content: source
        }
     },
    settings: {
        optimizer: {
            enabled: true
        },
        evmVersion: "byzantium",
        outputSelection: {
            "*": {
              "": [
                "legacyAST",
                "ast"
              ],
              "*": [
                "abi",
                "evm.bytecode.object",
                "evm.bytecode.sourceMap",
                "evm.deployedBytecode.object",
                "evm.deployedBytecode.sourceMap",
                "evm.gasEstimates"
              ]
            },
        }
    }
};

solcInput = JSON.stringify(solcInput);
var contractObject = solc.compile(solcInput);
contractObject = JSON.parse(contractObject);

console.log(contractObject);
```

Comment: This did the trick for me: it may take more code but no need to mess around with compiler versions.

Answer (score 8):

The version of solc and your contract should be the same.

For example, if your contract uses `pragma solidity ^0.4.18;` then you should install the same version of solc Using `npm install solc@0.4.18`.

Comment: This is the actual resolution for the error message. Both the versions of Solc and our pragma declaration in the contract should be same, or atleast compatable

Answer (score 2):

I too faced with the same problem. Download and check for the correct version of solc version is installed or else it gonna give you the error.I did not specify the version to download,it downloaded the default version.

> npm install --save solc@0.4.17
>   (specify the version)

"'{"errors":[{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"* Line 1, Column 1\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\n* Line 1, Column 2\n  Extra non-whitespace after JSON value.\n","message":"* Line 1, Column 1\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\n* Line 1, Column 2\n  Extra non-whitespace after JSON value.\n","severity":"error","type":"JSONError"}]}'"

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify what type of encoding is used for the solidity file.

```
code = fs.readFileSync('Voting.sol', 'utf8');
```

and you have to specifiy the number of contracts your are about to compile.

```
compiledCode = solc.compile(code, 1);
```

Comment: specifing the number of contract, gives out an AssertionError

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution. In my case the problem was that the `File.sol` was raw solidity smart contract, but you need to put `Compiler Standard Input JSON` into `solc.compile()`. This works for Solidity 0.5.1. In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53461034/solidity-compiler-problem-with-helloworld-smart-contract/53804796#53804796) is my whole process step by step until the transaction sending.