# Solidity compiler - problem with HelloWorld smart contract

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Im trying to run my first HelloWorld smart contract on the Enthereum network. This is my HelloWorld.sol contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract HelloWorld {
  bytes32 message;
  constructor (bytes32 myMessage) public {
    message = myMessage;
  }
  function getMessage() public returns(bytes32) {
    return message;
  }
}
```

When I try to build this using `solcjs HelloWorld.sol --bin`, there is just one Warning and no errors. I have installed web3 and solc using npm. When I run this on a node

```
var solc = require('solc');
var x = fs.readFileSync('./HelloWorld.sol').toString();
var compiledContract = solc.compile(x);
```

the `compiledContract`contains this:

```
'{"errors":[{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"* Line 1, Column 1\\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\\n* Line 1, Column 2\\n  Extra non-whitespace after JSON value.\\n","message":"* Line 1, Column 1\\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\\n* Line 1, Column 2\\n  Extra non-whitespace after JSON value.\\n","severity":"error","type":"JSONError"}]}'
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you try with an earlier version of the solidity compiler?

Comment: If I write pragma solidity ^0.4.x it throws error that I have version 0.5.0

Comment: I think you need to change the version of the compiler you have installed as well.

Comment: I changed the version to 0.4.18 but there is the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was, that you I can not put raw solidity smart contract into `solc.compile()` function. There must be `Compiler Standard Input JSON`. Based on my [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53795971/solidity-solidity-code-to-input-json-description/53798746#53798746) I found this solution:

```
> var Web3 = require('web3');
> var solc = require('solc');
> var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
> var CONTRACT_FILE = 'HelloWorld.sol'
> var content =fs.readFileSync(CONTRACT_FILE).toString()
> var input = {
  language: 'Solidity',
  sources: {
    [CONTRACT_FILE]: {
      content: content
    }
  },
  settings: {
    outputSelection: {
      '*': {
        '*': ['*']
      }
    }
  }
}

> var compiled = solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))
> var output = JSON.parse(compiled)
> var abi = output.contracts[CONTRACT_FILE]['HelloWorld'].abi
> var bytecode = output.contracts[CONTRACT_FILE]['HelloWorld'].evm.bytecode.object
> var HelloWorld = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
> var HelloWorldTx = HelloWorld.deploy({data: bytecode, arguments: [web3.utils.asciiToHex('Hello')]});
> web3.eth.estimateGas(HelloWorldTx).then(console.log); //this does not work, because it can not connect to the localhost:8545. I don't know why.
> HelloWorldTx.send({from: '0x99d54a45f2cd3b9c6443d623003416aaf944338e', gas: 1000000}).then(console.log);
```