# Solidity - Solidity code to Input JSON Description

Tags: npm, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I want to compile my ethereum HelloWorld.sol smart contract. In all the tutorials is that you do it like this:

```
var solc = require('solc');
var compiledContract = solc.compile(fs.readFileSync('HelloWorld.sol').toString();
```

where HelloWorld.sol is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract HelloWorld {
    bytes32 message;
    constructor(bytes32 myMessage) public {
        message = myMessage;
    }

    function getMessage() public view returns(bytes32){
        return message;
    }
}
```

In other words, I put my raw Solidity contract code into the solc.compile() method. But this process gives me this error in `compiledContract`:

```
'{"errors":[{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"* Line 1, Column 1\\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\\n* Line 1, Column 2\\n  Extra non-whitespace after JSON value.\\n","message":"* Line 1, Column 1\\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\\n* Line 1, Column 2\\n  Extra non-whitespace after JSON value.\\n","severity":"error","type":"JSONError"}]}'
```

I was looking for a solution for quite a long time, but the only thing I found is that

> "The high-level API consists of a single method, compile, which
> expects the Compiler Standard Input and Output JSON."

([link](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js)). The standard input JSON looks like some combination of JSON and this solidity code. So my question is -
How to transfer the solidity contract code into a compiler standard input JSON?
Am I correct that this is the only way how to compile the contract?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code works for me, index.js

```
const solc = require('solc')
const fs = require('fs')

const CONTRACT_FILE = 'HelloWorld.sol'

const content = fs.readFileSync(CONTRACT_FILE).toString()

const input = {
  language: 'Solidity',
  sources: {
    [CONTRACT_FILE]: {
      content: content
    }
  },
  settings: {
    outputSelection: {
      '*': {
        '*': ['*']
      }
    }
  }
}

const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)))

for (const contractName in output.contracts[CONTRACT_FILE]) {
  console.log(output.contracts[CONTRACT_FILE][contractName].evm.bytecode.object)
}
```

HelloWorld.sol

```
contract HelloWorld {
    bytes32 message;
    constructor(bytes32 myMessage) public {
        message = myMessage;
    }

    function getMessage() public view returns(bytes32){
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is basically what i wanted to do, but is there some way, how to create the content of the input automatically? Something like solc.CreateJSON(CONTRACT_FILE)?

Comment: hey maybe you can advise? `const appPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'inbox.sol');`
`const source = fs.readFileSync(appPath, 'utf8').toString();` getting the file in a very similar manner, but got `Invalid input source specified` error

Comment: Do you modify your content file anyhow before passing it here?

Comment: Try `const appPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './contracts/inbox.sol');` and maybe remove `''utf8''` in `fs.readFileSync()`. I didn't modify `content`

Comment: yeah i tried hardcoded paths and removing `utf-8` - same

Comment: Ok i got it, you forget to include json key `content` in your answer and i overlook it in doc. it must be: `[CONTRACT_FILE]: {
      content: content
    }`

Comment: Sorry about that, if key and value are same, you can write just one word, you can know more here https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand. Thanks for your feedback, will do my examples more readable next time =)

Comment: I re-cheked, code above with single `content` works on Node.js v8.12.0

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can run the solc (command line tool) with the below command and with input data

```
solc --standard-json   -o outputDirectory --bin --ast --asm HelloWorld.sol
```

Where in the above command when --standard-json expects a input json file that you can give.

You can find an example of how an input file should be in the below link.

Source: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/using-the-compiler.html

Answer (score 0):

```
const solc = require("solc");

// file system - read and write files to your computer
const fs = require("fs");

// reading the file contents of the smart  contract
const fileContent = fs.readFileSync("HelloWorld.sol").toString();

// create an input structure for my solidity compiler
var input = {
  language: "Solidity",
  sources: {
    "HelloWorld.sol": {
      content: fileContent,
    },
  },

  settings: {
    outputSelection: {
      "*": {
        "*": ["*"],
      },
    },
  },
};

var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
// console.log("Output: ", output);

const ABI = output.contracts["HelloWorld.sol"]["Demo"].abi;
const byteCode = output.contracts["HelloWorld.sol"]["Demo"].evm.bytecode.object;

// console.log("abi: ",ABI)
// console.log("byte code: ",byteCode)

npm run yorfilename.js
```